# Accessing class variables in PHP

Tags: php

I'm wondering why the following lines causes an error. `doSomething()` gets called from another PHP file.

```
class MyClass
{   
    private $word;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->word='snuffy';
    }   
    public function doSomething($email)
    {
        echo('word:');
        echo($this->word); //ERROR: Using $this when not in object context
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How are you calling the method?

Doing

```
MyClass::doSomething('user@example.com');
```

will fail, as it's not a static method, and you're not accessing a static variable.

However, doing

```
$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->doSomething('user@xample.com');
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

To use your class and method which are not `static`, you must instanciate your class :

```
$object = new MyClass();
$object->doSomething('test@example.com');
```

You cannot call your non-static method statically, like this :

```
MyClass::doSomething('test@example.com');
```

Calling this will get you :

- A warning *(I'm using PHP 5.3)* : `Strict standards: Non-static method MyClass::doSomething() should not be called statically`
- And, as your statically-called non-static method is using `$this` : `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context`

For more informations, you should read the [**Classes and Objects**][1] section of the manual -- and, for this specific question, its [**Static Keyword**][2] page.